# Error! Requested Url returned 405 - method not allowed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc, kendo-editor

```
$("#imgBrowser").kendoEditor({
    tools: [
        "insertImage"
    ],
    imageBrowser: {
        messages: {
            dropFilesHere: "Drop files here"
        },

        transport: {
            read: "/ImageBrowser/Read",
            destroy: {
                url: "/ImageBrowser/Destroy",
                type: "POST"
            },
            create: {
                url: "/ImageBrowser/Create",
                type: "POST"
            },
            thumbnailUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail",
            uploadUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Upload",
            imageUrl: "~/ImageGallery//Image?path={0}"
        },
        change: function () {
            //this.value(); //Selected image URL
        },
        select: function () {
        }
    }, execute: function (e) {           
    },
    change: function () {
    },
    select: function () {


    }
});
```

I am new to kendo Controls. i want to save images in my project folder. I am Using this code but it is not calling Controller Actions but when i am uploading image it is giving. images re also not saving in folder it is showing always loading icon. when i upload any image it is showing this below error.

```
  Error! Requested Url returned 405 - method not allowed
```

Please help me how can i resolve this error. and how can i save uploaded images into my project folder.

Comment: Did you add `HttpGet` attribute to the controller method? Add your controller method to this question.

Comment: Do you still have this issue ?I can help if needed.

Comment: we tried another way. any way thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your application web.config, This link help you through the way

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications